# MySQL calculating an average number of all players and updating the column

Tags: mysql

I have a game server, with over 15k player rows, and every player row has columns like kills, deaths, name, etc.

So doing it server sided, would be very bad, means I have to send 15k queries to get each player's kill/death ratio.

Basically what I need to do, get the kill/death average off the database.

I have a row, that has the following columns:

Total average, total kills, total players.

I need to find total average and total kills.

Total average is basically, I load each player, i take his kills, and deaths and divide them (kills/deaths). so total average contains all players kill/deaths ratios in it, and then being divided by player count.

Player count will be the amount of rows. and total kills be all of the kills in all of the rows.

How can I do this using SQL? and is it efficient to do?

Comment: can you provide some sample data? mysql has aggregate functions like count() where you can count the amount of rows... also doing it server side doesn't usually mean you have to do 15k queries.. depends on what data you have.. but you should be able to do that in a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Average kill/death ratio:

```
SELECT AVG(kills/death) AS avg_kd FROM players
```

Total players:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot_players FROM players
```

Total kills:

```
SELECT SUM(kills) AS tot_kills FROM players
```

All of the above queries scan through all records. It's not really efficient, but there's no other way to do it unless you store these values and update them with triggers.

If you need further help, please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is the best place to do this. 
Lets say you have a table, playrtstats, with 15k rows with the following fields: playerid, kills, deaths, plays...

average kill to death ration for all players:

```
select sum(kills)/sum(deaths) from playerstats;
```

want to know the ten players with the lowest death per play ratio?

```
select deaths/plays from playerstats order by 1 asc limit 10;
```